# adding Sticky FAB in Angular 2 Material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I want to add a sticky button at the bottom of screen (not page) in my angular 2  material project.
I tried some tweaks but currently when I scroll down the button doesn't stays where it was supposed to be.

before scroll it looks like below:

[image: before scroll]

after scroll:

[image: after wcroll]

Elements's HTML inside template:

```
<a md-fab id="fab">
    <md-icon>add</md-icon>
</a>
```

CSS Applied on the Element Except for any defaults:

```
#fab{
    position: fixed;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
}
```

1. How can I fix this?
2. Additionally is there any built in way with Angular material to do what I want?

**UPDATE:**

My main component's Template:

```
<toolbar></toolbar>
<side-nav></side-nav>
```

Side Nav's Template:

```
<md-sidenav-container id="sidenav-container">

    // contents

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

and its CSS:

```
#sidenav-container { // styling to make side nav of full height
    position: fixed;
    height: 90%;
    min-height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

and then inside the component added by the router-outlet will come FAB element.

Notes-list component's template (the one shown in the images):

```
<a md-fab id="fab">
    <md-icon>add</md-icon>
</a>

//rest of the content
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sticky-fab-in-angular-2-material)**

Answer (score 12):

You are correct to put the router-outlet within the md-sidenav-container.

Add the follow class to your FAB element.

```
.md-fab-bottom-right2 {
    top: auto !important;
    right: 20px !important;
    bottom: 10px !important;
    left: auto !important;
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

This is how I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom class and apply your styles also look for the hierarchy in which files are referenced to DOM

```
<div class="example-container">    

  <h3>sticky icons</h3>
  <a class="mine" md-fab routerLink=".">
    <md-icon>check</md-icon>
  </a>
  <a md-mini-fab routerLink=".">
    <md-icon>check</md-icon>
  </a>

</div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/EVhud06lnOGFkmFQT1sd?p=preview)**

Update 1 :
You are using the icon inside the md-sidenav container which is a mistake

```
<div class="example-container">
  <md-sidenav-container>

    <md-sidenav #sidenav>
      <p>side nav works</p>
    </md-sidenav>

  </md-sidenav-container>
    <p>content</p>
    <a class="mine" md-fab (click)="sidenav.open()">
      <md-icon>check</md-icon>
    </a>

</div>
```

**[Updated Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/V7hb21JNtT65nHGkooCw?p=preview)**

Update 2 :

Look at the below code, you are  wrapping everything inside sidenav which is wrong. Use as below

```
<md-sidenav-container id="sidenav-container">    </md-sidenav-container>
        // contents
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Then I must be missing something else, you applied the same styling on FAB and it worked perfectly.

Comment: look into your hierarchy of references

Comment: I have added my component's heirarchy. I guess side-nav-container's css must be causing problem.

Comment: not the component hierarchy. stylesheets hierarchy you need to look for

Comment: have a look at the live demo i provided. I added your plunk's contents inside a sidenav.

Comment: but doing that breaks the sidenav,

if you noticed, it appears below any other content.

Comment: what is your expectation? tell me I will fix

Comment: this is new plunker link regarding what I was saying:

https://plnkr.co/edit/OSMha8XJFgmCnxkjUqHS?p=preview

Comment: its not working,
changing the nesting causes issues with the sidenav, main content is hidden, also FAB appears on top of sidenav when sidenav is opened unlike before when button wasn't fixed.

Comment: are you available in team viewer/

Comment: how sidenav appears in my project:

[image](http://i.imgur.com/4ljUcrN.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143004/discussion-between-saif-ullah-and-aravind).